# Is there any history and current weather API that can check the weather of only INDIAN cities?

Tags: weather-api

I would like to check the current as well as historical weather of only the cities of India. If there is an API to do the same, please provide me the link to that API.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/